# Does altova mapforce exposes any REST APIS?

Tags: rest, altova, map-force

I am new to altova mapforce. I wanted to know that does Altova Mapforce exposes any kind of REST APIS so that we can supply it the input from a single page web application and get the data from the tool back in any format (JSON, XML)?

Answer (score 0):

MapForce version 2022 rel 2 still can't expose REST services, only SOAP.
The SOAP service has to be compiled in an ASPX app and run on IIS.

It can consume REST and SOAP services.

You can create a REST service with the FlowForce/MapForce servers.
However ist does not support CORS.
It wouldn't work with a Single Page Web App.